# How to access elements of Collections Counter stored as column in dataframe to be used in CountVectorizer

Tags: python, pandas, collections

One of the columns in the dataframe is in the following format

```
Row 1 : 
Counter({'First': 3, 'record': 2})
Row 2 : 
Counter({'Second': 2, 'record': 1}).
```

I want to create a new column which has the following value:

```
Row 1 :
First First First record record
Row 2 : 
Second Second record
```

Comment: I edited both your question and the tags - it has nothing to do with `regex` imo. Also where does this data come from? Maybe it's better to fix the issues up the river.

Comment: I was able to solve the question myself by the following code. It is very much related to regex.

    def transform_word_count(text):
        words = re.findall(r'\'(.+?)\'',text)
        n = re.findall(r"[0-9]",text)
        result = []
        for i in range(len(words)):
            for j in range(int(n[i])):
                result.append(words[i])
        return result

    df['new'] = df.apply(lambda row: transform_word_count(row['old']), axis=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the question myself by the following code. It is very much related to regex.

```
def transform_word_count(text):
    words = re.findall(r'\'(.+?)\'',text)
    n = re.findall(r"[0-9]",text)
    result = []
    for i in range(len(words)):
        for j in range(int(n[i])):
            result.append(words[i])
    return result

df['new'] = df.apply(lambda row: transform_word_count(row['old']), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `apply` with iter values of `counter` and join with space - first repeated values and then together:

```
import ast

#convert values to dictionaries
df['col'] = df['col'].str.extract('\((.+)\)', expand=False).apply(ast.literal_eval)

df['new'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(' '.join([k] * v) for k, v in x.items()))
print (df)
                          col                              new
0   {'First': 3, 'record': 2}  First First First record record
1  {'Second': 2, 'record': 1}             Second Second record
```

Or list comprehension:

```
df['new'] = [' '.join(' '.join([k] * v) for k, v in x.items()) for x in df['col']]
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I am getting the following error : "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'". I guess this is because though my column in the format {}, it is not a list but a string. Kindly let me know if you have any updates for it to work.

Comment: @Vincent - Use `df['col'] = df['col'].str.extract('\((.+)\)', expand=False).apply(ast.literal_eval)` - answer was edited.